# Start and Stop Profiling from Javascript in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I would love to be able to start and stop the CPU Profiler in the Chrome developer window by making a javascript call.  Something like:

```
chrome.cpuprofiler.start();  
//do expensive operation  
chrome.cpuprofiler.stop();
```

Right now, the best I can do is:

```
Click "start profiling".  
//do expensive operation  
Click "stop profiling".
```

Is there even a shortcut key for this?

Answer (score 62):

You can!

An example:

```
   if (window.console && window.console.profile) {
     console.profile("label for profile");
     // insert code to profile here,
     // all function calls will be profiled
     console.profileEnd();
   }
```

It also works on Safari, and with Firebug in Firefox.

**Note:** You can't use profile to time code that does not make a function call: if your code above is simply a for loop then the profiler won't find anything to profile.  Use `console.time()` and `console.timeEnd()`  to benchmark pure loops or code that does not call a function.